# Ruby, подсчет количества вхождений в массив строк

Tags: ruby

Сущетсвует массив хэшей :

```
arr[{fam='Иванов' name=>'Иван' otch=>'Иванович' year=>'1973', prof=>"водитель, монтажник"}, 
    {fam='Петров' name=>'Петр' otch=>'Петрович' year=>'1967' prof=>"слесарь, монтажник, сантехник"}},
    {...}]
```

требуется подсчитать количество слесарей, монтажников, и пр. профессий. Не могу понять каким методом этого достичь, и сделать бы это еще красиво)
Пробовал метод count но ничего не вышло:

```
arr.map{ |ar| ar["prof"].split(",") }.flatten.uniq!.sort.each{ |a| puts a + " - " + arr.count(a){|ar, a| ar["prof"].include? a }.to_s }
```

Comment: Что бы выделить в вопросе код, нажмите на фигурные скобки `{}` в редакторе.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Hash[ arr.
  flat_map{ |man| man[:prof].split(", ") }.
  group_by(&:itself).
  map{ |prof, group| [prof, group.size] }
]
```

Если Ruby версии меньше, чем 2.2, то вместо `(&:itself)` будет `{ |i| i }`

---

Или:

```
require "mll"

result = MLL::tally[ arr.
  flat_map{ |man| man[:prof].split(", ") }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй так:

```
arr.inject({}) do |memo, element|
  profs = element[:prof].split(",\s")
  profs.each do |prof|
    memo[prof] = 0 unless memo.key?(prof)
    memo[prof] += 1
  end
  memo
end
```